# Grails project deployed on server successfully but not getting up on browser

Tags: grails, amazon-ec2, server, tomcat7

i had deployed my project on Aws ec2 server according to this link: http://grails.asia/step-by-step-tutorial-on-how-to-host-your-grails-application

And its has been deployed successfully as my bootstrap has been executed and i
have given some println in it which are getting shown on tomcat's catalina.out.
and also the bootstraped data has been already inserted into mysql db. I
guess, it means that my application is running somewhere.  But when i am trying
to hit the url according to above link its not getting dispalyed on browser.

I am hitting : https://35.154.163.145:8080/jobVacency/ 
where "35.154.163.145" is my aws IPv4 Public IP and 
jobVacency is my project name.

Catalina.out:

```
Apr 14, 2017 8:19:19 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://www.springframework.org/tags/form is already defined
Apr 14, 2017 8:19:20 AM org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.MetaInfExtensionModule newModule
WARNING: Module [groovy-all] - Unable to load extension class [org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NioGroovyMethods]
Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core

Bootstrap started.

Bootstrap ended.

Apr 14, 2017 8:19:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /va`enter code here`r/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT
Apr 14, 2017 8:19:50 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Apr 14, 2017 8:19:50`enter code here` AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 42043 ms
```

Comment: Sure it's not `jobVacancy`?

Comment: @tim_yates But whenerver i run my project on local machine the url is "localhost:8080/jobVacency".

Comment: What's the name of the WAR file you are deploying on the server?

Comment: @JoshuaMoore its jobVacency-0.1.war

Comment: Issue Resolved!!! It was restricted by aws firewall. Had to open port 8080 from aws inbound security. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Is the port correct? Please check which port the server is running in.